# Why isn't python waiting for my function to finish?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, tkinter

So I'm using tkinter and Python to write an app to control some devices over serial. In this case I am controlling a temperature bath and I have a simple function that waits until that bath has reached a temperature I have set called `wait_for_temp()`. I thought that `control_fcn()` which I've included below would wait until the `bc.wait_for_temp()` call completes, but instead if just runs through the rest of the `control_fcn()`. Anyone know why? Is this because of my call to `app.after()`?

```
def control_fcn()
  bc = Bath_Controller()

  # set the temperature I want
  set_temp = 16.0
  bc.write_temp(set_temp)

  print("Commanding temp to " + str(set_temp))

  bc.turn_on()

  # wait for bath temp to be within .1 of the commanded temp
  # this function prints out a "Temperature reached. Carry on." statement when done
  bc.wait_for_temp(set_temp)

  print("I didn't wait for you friend.")

# in my Bath_Controller() class I have the following function
def wait_for_temp(self, set_temp):
  current_temp = self.read_temp()
  if (current_temp < set_temp + .05) and (current_temp > set_temp - .05):
    print("Temperature reached. Carry on.")
    return
  else:
    print("Waiting for temperature equilibration.\n Current temp is:")
    # app here is my root window in tkinter
    app.after(10000, lambda: self.wait_for_temp(set_temp))
```

Comment: `wait_for_temp` does not actually wait for anything, because `after` is not a blocking operation. It sends a request to the Tkinter engine saying, "hey, call this function in ten thousand milliseconds", and then it near-instantaneously returns control back to the scope that called `after`. If you want to block, use `sleep`. If this causes your GUI to freeze solid for ten seconds, you may need to do some extensive redesigning. (the details of which can't be determined without seeing your entire code, which is why I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does wait for `wait_for_temp` to complete. `wait_for_temp` will return almost immediately, however. Calling `after` doesn't prevent it from returning. Quite the contrary, calling `after` allows it to return without waiting.

Writing a GUI is different from writing non-GUI programs. A GUI is already  in a perpetual state of waiting. Instead of writing a function that itself waits, you need to write code that can respond to events.

For example, you can create a `<<TemperatureReached>>` event that can be triggered when the temperature hits a given value. You can then bind a function to be called when that event triggers.

It would look something like this:

```
def control_fcn()
    bc = Bath_Controller()

    # set the temperature I want
    set_temp = 16.0
    bc.write_temp(set_temp)

    # arrange for notifyUser to be called when the target
    # temperature has been reached
    app.bind("<<TemperatureReached>>", self.notifyUser)

    # periodically check the temp
    self.check_temp(set_temp)

def notifyUser(event):
    print("Temperature reached")

def check_temp(self, set_temp):
    current_temp = self.read_temp()
    if (current_temp < set_temp + .05) and (current_temp > set_temp - .05):
        # temperature reached; send an event
        app.event_generate("<<TemperatureReached>>")
    else:
        # temperature not reached. Check again in 10 seconds
        app.after(10000, self.check_temp, set_temp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. This may be beyond the scope of this question, but my control_fcn() actually has a bunch of calls to set different temperatures and some logic in between calls that needs to wait until the temp is reached. I would like to have all of that inside control_fcn() but for that it would need to stop and wait. How would you deal with multiple calls from that same function?

Comment: @clifgray  Why can't you put that "bunch of calls" in a function that is called when the temperature is set? Why must it all be in a single monolithic function?

Comment: Well I suppose I should but each one of these calls has some aspect of waiting for a serial device to finish a task it. It seemed cleaner to use a single larger function rather than go down a rabbit hole 3 functions deep: waiting for a temp change, and then for each temp change waiting for some valves to open, and then running some tasks once those valves open. I may be wrong about that though. I realize this is hard to comment on without seeing the specific code.

Comment: You are correct that it's hard to comment without seeing more code. Though, if each step were a function it seems pretty easy to set up bindings that go from `<<TemperatureReached>>` to `<<ValveOpened>>` to `<<SystemReady>>` or whatever. Ultimately that's what you're doing, right? "do this, and wait for this event, then do this, and wait for this event, and then do this".

Answer (score 1):

The `after` method is designed to return immediately. The point of useing after rather than a `while True:` loop is that it returns immediately and does not lockup the GUI. To get what you want you will have to split it up:

```
def control_fcn()
  bc = Bath_Controller()

  # set the temperature I want
  set_temp = 16.0
  bc.write_temp(set_temp)

  print("Commanding temp to " + str(set_temp))

  bc.turn_on()

  # wait for bath temp to be within .1 of the commanded temp
  # this function prints out a "Temperature reached. Carry on." statement when done
  bc.wait_for_temp(set_temp)

def done():
  print("I didn't wait for you friend.")

# in my Bath_Controller() class I have the following function
def wait_for_temp(self, set_temp):
  current_temp = self.read_temp()
  if (current_temp < set_temp + .05) and (current_temp > set_temp - .05):
    print("Temperature reached. Carry on.")
    done()
  else:
    print("Waiting for temperature equilibration.\n Current temp is:")
    # app here is my root window in tkinter
    app.after(10000, lambda: self.wait_for_temp(set_temp))
```

Answer (score -1):

In `app.after()` you are basically saying run this piece of code after 10 seconds, however you're not instructing the processor to `wait 10 seconds` in conjunction.

The simple solution is to wrap your function `wait_for_temp()` in a proper `while loop` and wait until you have the desired output, i.e.:

```
# in my Bath_Controller() class I have the following function
def wait_for_temp(self, set_temp):
    while 1:
        current_temp = self.read_temp()
        if (current_temp < set_temp + .05) and (current_temp > set_temp - .05):
            print("Temperature reached. Carry on.")
            return
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hmm I suppose this would meet the basic requirements. But as Kevin points out, using `time.sleep()` freezes the tkinter GUI.